# Differences between ways of creating ImmutableList

Tags: c#, immutable-collections

What is the differences between ways of creating ImmutableList?

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>(){0, 1, 2, 3};
ImmutableList<int> immutableList = numbers.ToImmutableList();

ImmutableList<int> immutableList = ImmutableList.Create<int>(0, 1, 2, 3);

ImmutableList<int> immutableList = ImmutableList.CreateRange<int>(new List<int>() { 0, 1, 2, 3 });

ImmutableList<int>.Builder builder = ImmutableList.CreateBuilder<int>();
builder.AddRange(new List<int>() { 0, 1, 2, 3 });
ImmutableList<int> immutableList = builder.ToImmutableList();
```

Which is the faster and usabel?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "better"

Comment: @TheodorZoulias read about it in "Concurrency in C# Cookbook" by Stephen Cleary. He wrote that this is a safe thread collection.

Comment: M.Jaskuski the immutable collections are thread-safe indeed, sort of, but the tags are used to characterize the question, and AFAICS your question is not about multithreading programming!

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I deleted the tag before your first question. Thank you for your observation!

Comment: *"Which is the best?"* -- I would suggest to replace this question with something more specific, because this is a too generic question to ask, and it might attract downvotes!

Comment: @TheodorZoulias What are you thinking about: "Which is the faster and usabel?" ?

Comment: Faster and usable are orthogonal properties. The faster might be the less usable, and the most usable might be the slowest. Such a question would attract close-votes for being "too broad, needs more focus"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at how each of those is implemented.

First off, the `ToImmutableList()` extension method involves first trying to cast to `ImmutableList<T>`, and then falling back to `ImmutableList<T>.Empty.AddRange()` otherwise. `ImmutableList.Create()` and `ImmutableList.CreateRange()` also call `ImmutableList<T>.Empty.AddRange()`.

Finally, the builder is the only one that has some key difference, although you're using it wrong: you should be using `ToImmutable()`, because it involves doing fewer unecessary copies. `ToImmutableList()` just uses the above extension method, and therefore also uses `ImmutableList<T>.Empty.AddRange()`.

Really, if you're building a possibly large immutable list as you go, you should use a builder, and then freeze it with `ToImmutable()` when you're done modifying it. Otherwise, all the other methods are functionally identical, so pick whichever is clearest to you.